# Tomcat and Netbeans. No server selected

Tags: java, tomcat

I installed Tomcat 9.0 in my computer and integrated it in Netbeans.
When I try to run a .jsp file I can't select any server to run the code in. I previously started the server in Netbeans successfully. See Screenshot.
Does anybody know what the problem is?

[image]

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: How are you accessing that "deployment server" pop-up window? The usual way to assign a web project to Tomcat is as follows: Right-click on your project name in the left hand column (the name is not legible in your screenshot - sorry). You will see a context menu. Choose "Run". There you will see an option to select a "Server" from a drop-down list. This list will show you the configured servers (such as Tomcat) which are available to NetBeans.

Comment: Also, in case it helps: If you have configured your web project to use Tomcat, then your web project should automatically start and stop Tomcat for you, whenever you choose to start and stop your web project. (So, I typically never start/stop Tomcat in NetBeans myself, unless something has gone wrong. I let my project take care of starting and stopping Tomcat.)

Comment: The problem is that the dropdown to select the server is empty. No server is available although the server is already started. See screenshot in the edit

Comment: OK - stop the server first (like I say, the app takes care of starting and stopping it - you do not have to).

Comment: If that does not work, then my recommendation is that you [edit] your question to provide a step-by-step description of (1) how you downloaded and installed Tomcat, (2) how you then added that Tomcat installation to NetBeans, and (3) how you configured your NetBeans web app to use Tomcat. In other words, enough details for us to recreate the problem for ourselves. Currently, I do not know how to recreate your problem.

Comment: It work! the point is what you wrote in your first comment. Thanks!